# Android open another app in my app window

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open other app in my app window. 
Right now, I am using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` to do it.

For some apps, it works fine (1st screen), but for others this doesn't work (2nd screen).
How can I open YouTube in my app?

Maybe is there some way do it using root access?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAqjN.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG2KW.jpg)

My code :

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: "I want to open other app in my app window" -- I believe that you mean "task". "How do i can open youtube in my app?" -- there is no requirement that other apps allow you to do this.

Comment: @CommonsWare but i want to do that

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible?

Comment: "but i want to do that" -- get a job a Google, join the team that maintains the Android YouTube app, and make the change. Otherwise, they are welcome to use manifest settings to control what task their launcher activity goes into.

Comment: @CommonsWare there's a way with using root access?

Comment: I doubt that root access helps here, but I cannot rule it out.

Comment: @CommonsWare well, thanks for help! I will try find something with root access...

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry for so many questions, but... From what depends this launch option?

Comment: A variety of manifest values control task behavior, such as `android:taskAffinity`.

Comment: @Adel Dolgov, Do you want to open your app on top of another app like app lockers or you want to open other apps inside your application..?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran i want to open other apps inside my application. But some apps cant do this. Is there way to do this, even using root access?